# Error: "Column 'date_created' cannot be null" When trying to create entities

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, timestamp

I have an entity Recipe, which besides all attributes also holds an attribute of `java.sql.Timestamp` corresponding to column `date_created TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in my database. I understand that jpa is providing the database with a null value of Timestamp, but I cannot think of a fix. Ideally, when inserting a new recipe, jpa should not provide a non-null value for Timestamp, but rather let database give it the default value. Or atleast this is my idea. Any idea how to help me overcome with this error? Thank you

Comment: You can also add `@DynamicInsert` annotation to you entity, but this has disadvantages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721818/why-does-hibernate-set-dynamic-insert-false-by-default

Comment: @Selaron I probably missed that topic when searching before this post. It worked out. Thank you